# How to fix "Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found" error?

Tags: java, android

In my app, I'm trying to connect with API using hashmap from a fragment. The issue seems to be that the async task through which I'm connecting to the API doesn't want to accept my request. The error says Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

It is an app, where I use spinner so a user can choose, depending on his choice, different data will be loaded. I tried to fiddle around in hash map, but the issue now seems to be in the creating task.

this is my spinner where I initiate the task

```
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                       int position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Location selected: "+locations[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT )
                    .show();
            map.get(locations[position]);
            //create the task
                ChooseLocationTask task = new ChooseLocationTask(location, position, value);
            // start the task
                task.execute();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

and here is the constructor for the async task, that seems to be not working as well:

```
        this.location = location;
        this.value = value;
        String url ="";
        switch(selected){
            case 1:
                url = url1.getUrl();
                break;
            case 2:
                url= url2.getUrl();
                break;
            case 3:
                url= url3.getUrl();
                break;
            case 4:
                url= url4.getUrl();
                break;
            case 5:
                url = url5.getUrl();
                break;
            case 6:
                url = url6.getUrl();
                break;
            case 7:
                url = url7.getUrl();
                break;
            case 8:
                url= url8.getUrl();
                break;
            case 9:
                url = url9.getUrl();
        }
        request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    }
```

The error in the logcat said that the issue is in creating the task in the first code example and request in the second example.
I would like the user to see values from API when clicking on some of the fields in the spinner. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is url1,2,3 here ? Which class does it belongs ?

Comment: I have a special class of url class from where I'm getting the constructor. the urls are here just strings that look like this: `Urls url1 = new Urls("http://api.auroras.live/v1/?type=all&lat=40.7813913&long=-73.976902&forecast=false&threeday=false") ;`

Comment: The URL you have added in comment is a valid one . Please Debug your code for which case is getting executed there maybe a invalid URL . On a Side note just put all those urls in a `List` and get them with index i.e- Spinner index-->List index ..

Comment: I don't understand why you have a special object for a string. Just pass the string, your `url` variable is typed to string anyway `String url ="";`. It's just URLs, not neural surgery.

Comment: @reportgunner no need for negativity here. I'm developing in android for maybe three months, so yes, I don't know all the right ways to do things. But hey, that is the reason why I came here to get a suggestion. And I'm sorry if I'm too slow for you but I didn't get what to do how from your answer and frankly would prefer to see a code example for that.

Comment: @AlbínaMrázová I'm sorry if my comment came off as negative, if you read it again you will see that I wrote only that I don't understand why you do this. I have zero experience programming android and I don't see majority of your code, that's why I wrote that "I don't understand". If people don't do exactly what you expect they are not automatically negative. Also the downvote is not from me.

Comment: Perhaps your URLs have to be dynamically generated or you want to obscure stuff - I can't know this. How can I know what the `.getUrl()` returns if you haven't posted the definition ?

Answer (score 9):

URL must start with `http://` or `https://`, your url is `""`

EDIT: another possible problem that I see is that you don't have a `default:` branch in your switch statement - if variable `selected` has value of less than 1 or more than 9 your url will be empty and thus will not start with `http://` or `https://`

Also it seems you never use the variable called `value`. Maybe you meant to use that in your switch statement ?

Comment: My urls start with it, I have all of them defined as a string from my URL class like this: `Urls url1 = new Urls("http://api.auroras.live/v1/?type=all&lat=40.7813913&long=-73.976902&forecast=false&threeday=false") ; `

Comment: @AlbínaMrázová what is the value of url after the switch statement? Print it out

Comment: that's why there is an error. URL value is still empty after switch case. check to se what your "selected" value is. it is probably not between 1 - 9, or your corresponding url1 - url9 value is empty

Comment: @reportgunner I just added the default and logged it. You were right, it doesn't land to any url, but then I don't know how else to pass the urls. My initial issue here is that I need user to choose what he wants to see and based on that he should hit the right endpoint. That is why I did the switch statement. but since the url doesn't land, I kinda feel lost about it again

Comment: what is `this.value = value;` for ? didn't you mean `switch(this.value){` ?

Comment: @reportgunner value is seeing one of the objects from API, I just thought, that since I need to set it, later on, it should be there probably from the beginning, even if empty

Comment: @AlbínaMrázová so how does `selected` in `switch(selected){` get a value ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to add **"base URL"** in retrofit creation.So,even in this case it throws error.

**Error**:

```
 return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
        .baseUrl(" ")  //Here I had missed url
        .build()
```

**Correct:**

```
  return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)   //Add URL in place of base url
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is adding INTERNET permission to the project.
Add the following line to AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score -1):

in My case i was using `baseUrl` like you.

Changing it to `baseURL` (URL uppercase) it works fine.

Comment: Ture, I also used a wrong name while calling my baseurl, it was "BaseURL" in my local file and I wrote it in my gradle as "BaseUrl"