# Apollo on android: can't download schema or generate classes

Tags: windows, gradle, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying Apollo and graphql for the first time and I want to use [this api](https://countries.trevorblades.com/) and I'm following the official example [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/tutorial/02-add-the-graphql-schema/). However

running the schema download task

```
gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema --endpoint='https://countries.trevorblades.com/' --schema='app/src/main/graphql/com/trevorblades/countries/schema.json'
```

results in

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:downloadApolloSchema'.
> Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
```

with both the repo I want to use and the example's.

If I try to manually download the schema using the button on the repo's page, place it in the correct directory and run

```
gradlew generateApolloSources
```

it results in

```
 Failed to parse GraphQL schema introspection query from `[...]app\src\main\graphql\com\trevorblades\countries\schema.json`
```

again with both my repo and the one from the example.

I've the feeling that I'm missing something really trivial here, but I really can't figure it out.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: introspection query can be simply blocked (or auth required) on public/production APIs ... test it using postman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [JS GraphQL](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-js-graphql) IDEA plugin, which might make life a tad easier. And as it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271789/how-to-fix-expected-url-scheme-http-or-https-but-no-colon-was-found-error) ...you might not pass a valid endpoint at all. Try `--endpoint=https://countries.trevorblades.com/` or in `"` double-quotes . The error message is definitely concerning the `--endpoint` and not concerning the `--schema`. I have the suspicion that Windows might not like these `'` single quotes
(obviously the same would also apply to `--schema`).

```
gradlew.bat :app:downloadApolloSchema --endpoint=https://countries.trevorblades.com/ --schema=app/src/main/graphql/com/trevorblades/countries/schema.json
```

or:

```
gradlew.bat :app:downloadApolloSchema --endpoint="https://countries.trevorblades.com/" --schema="app/src/main/graphql/com/trevorblades/countries/schema.json"
```